# Is it Possible to Configure a Dell DRAC from Windows (without Rebooting)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell, drac, dell-openmanage

One of our Dell R610 servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't have it's Enterprise DRAC configured. Is there a utility (or perhaps a way from OpenManage) to configure the DRAC without rebooting and doing it via the BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you want to use the racadm utility.  As I recall, there's a download on the Dell drivers site for the DRAC tools.